# Insert empty string rather NULL in ssms insert query for the column names not specified

Tags: ssms

I've tried the syntax
`Insert into table_name (Col_names) Values (Values)`
which is inserting null values to the columns that i didn't mentioned the column name.
but i need it to be empty string rather NULL.
Is it possible to achieve in SSMS?

Comment: You really have 2 choices - either specify the column names and use '' (2 x single-quotes) as the "value", or else in the underlying table design, set empty string as their default value.  (If a column allows Nulls, but is not specified in an INSERT, then SQL's default behaviour is to just put Null values)

Comment: I would, personally, question the decision to put an empty string in those columns, especially when I suspect some of those columns likely aren't a string based data types.

Comment: As you've only tagged SSMS, are you therefore asking how to do this with the SSMS GUI only too? Is T-SQL off-limits?

Comment: @ThomA like using in C# too.

Comment: I've no idea what your point is there.